# SQL Selecting one row, displaying several

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I've been looking everywhere for a tutorial, but nothing quite fits what I need, so I'm almost guessing what I want isn't possible.

I have a table that contains an ID for a batch of product, followed by several test results (i.e. BatchNumber, Type, TestResultOne, TestResultTwo, etc...). There are thirty tests in total, for each batch.

I am trying to create a select statement or a view that displays the batch number, the ordinal_position of the test column (i.e. 3 for TestResultOne) and the value of that result. So when I run the select statement in my database, I receive one row, but when I run my select/view, I need 29 rows (one for each of the tests conducted on the product).

Is this possible? If so: is there a tutorial out there showing me how to do it, and if not, how the heck do I get around this issue?

For example, my table looks like so:

```
BatchID | Type | TestOne | TestTwo | TestThree | Test Four 
----------------------------------------------------------
00001   |  A   |   1.2   |   0     |  16       |   PASS
00002   |  A   |   1.3   |   1     |  15       |   FAIL
```

and I am hoping to get:

```
BatchID | Test | Result
-----------------------
00001   |  2   |  1.2
00001   |  3   |  0
00001   |  4   | 16
00001   |  5   | PASS
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data

Comment: Is my example above enough? Cheers

Comment: You could normalize your base table.  Instead of having TestOne, TestTwo, TestThree, etc you would have a TestNumber column.  This should be easy to query to give you the results you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify the base table - I have to work with it, which is a pain!

Comment: In your table you have 5 column names and 6 entries in each row. Are you missing a column name?

Comment: I've made that amendment, thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible you need to you a [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and there are two types `STATIC` and `DYNAMIC` what you need is a `DYNAMIC UNPIVOT`

Comment: Could you provide me with an example statement that links closely to my data? I've had a look at some examples online and they don't quite work (I'm using SQL Server to run these by the way)

Comment: I am in the process of writing the code as answer. Can you add the name of your table?

Comment: My table is called "Batches" - thanks!

Comment: @WillWhitehead Instead of writing 29 select statements for you 29 columns try to look at and run the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26384984/2246380) I wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you need to do is UNPIVOT your table.  Depending of the version of SQL Server one could use the UNPIVOT statement.  I prefer UNIONing the results instead of using the UNPIVOT syntax.
Something like the following should work for you.

```
DECLARE @TestResults TABLE (
    BatchID Int,
    TestType CHAR(1),
    TestOne SMALLMONEY,
    TestTwo SMALLMONEY,
    TestThree SMALLMONEY,
    TestFour SMALLMONEY
)
INSERT INTO @TestResults
SELECT 1, 'A', 1.2, 0, 16, 8.2 UNION
SELECT 2, 'A', 1.3, 1, 15, 7.4

SELECT BatchID, TestType, TestOne, TestTwo, TestThree, TestFour FROM @TestResults
```

This will return your current results.

```
BatchID     TestType TestOne     TestTwo     TestThree   TestFour
----------- -------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           A        1.20        0.00        16.00       8.20
2           A        1.30        1.00        15.00       7.40
```

Try the following query to UNPIVOT your data.

```
SELECT BatchID, 1 AS Test, TestOne AS Result FROM @TestResults UNION ALL
SELECT BatchID, 2 AS Test, TestTwo FROM @TestResults  UNION ALL
SELECT BatchID, 3 AS Test, TestThree FROM @TestResults  UNION ALL
SELECT BatchID, 4 AS Test, TestFour  FROM @TestResults 
ORDER BY BatchID, Test
```

This should return the desired results.

```
BatchID     Test        Result
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1.20
1           2           0.00
1           3           16.00
1           4           8.20
2           1           1.30
2           2           1.00
2           3           15.00
2           4           7.40
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian! But I tried running your code and it wouldn't compile, let alone me trying to modify it to make it run on my instance of MS SQL Server... (I'm using SQL Server 2008)

Comment: If you copy the code with out the results.  It will run on SQL Server 2008.  What error are you receiving?

Comment: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = DECLARE ]"

Literally copied and pasted the first grey box's code

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to run the query or something else?

Comment: Try running
'SELECT BatchID, 1 AS Test, TestOne AS Result FROM Batch UNION ALL
SELECT BatchID, 2 AS Test, TestTwo FROM Batch  UNION ALL
SELECT BatchID, 3 AS Test, TestThree FROM Batch  UNION ALL
SELECT BatchID, 4 AS Test, TestFour  FROM Batch 
ORDER BY BatchID, Test'

Comment: Hi @WillWhitehead if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM sys.columns c
           WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Batches') 
           AND  c.name NOT IN ('BatchID', 'Type')
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')


SET @query =
  N'SELECT BatchID, Type, Col as Test, Val as Result
FROM
(
select BatchID, Type, ' + @cols + '
from Batches
) as cp
unpivot
(
Val for Col in (' + @cols + ')
) as up'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

To explain the code first we are creating a list of the columns of your table which you want as rows thus excluding `BatchID` and `Type` using [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

```
SET @cols = STUFF((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM sys.columns c
           WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Batches') 
           AND  c.name NOT IN ('BatchID', 'Type')
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Then we are using the column names and performing an [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) using the column names on your table `Batches`

```
SET @query =
  N'SELECT BatchID, Type, Col as Test, Val as Result
FROM
(
select BatchID, Type, ' + @cols + '
from Batches
) as cp
unpivot
(
Val for Col in (' + @cols + ')
) as up'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

**SQL Fiddle Demo** : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54977/6

Comment: The only problem I have with this answer (which is by far the most efficient answer) is that within my SQL Server Management Studio 2008, it doesn't 'compile'. I get the response: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = DECLARE ]